# Test if calling f(x) is possible using metaprogramming

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming

The Stroustrup's book provides an example how to answer the question: "is it possible to call `f(x)` if `x` is of type `X`" (the section 28.4.4 "Further examples with Enable_if"). I've tried to reproduce the example but got something wrong and can't understand what.

In my code below, there is a function `f(int)`. I expect that then the result of `has_f<int>::value` is `1` (`true`). The actual result is `0` (`false`).

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

//
// Meta if/then/else specialization
//
struct substitution_failure { };

template<typename T>
struct substitution_succeeded : std::true_type { };

template<>
struct substitution_succeeded<substitution_failure> : std::false_type { };

//
// sfinae to derive the specialization
//
template<typename T>
struct get_f_result {
private:
  template<typename X>
    static auto check(X const& x) -> decltype(f(x));
  static substitution_failure check(...);
public:
  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};

//
// has_f uses the derived specialization
//
template<typename T>
struct has_f : substitution_succeeded<typename get_f_result<T>::type> { };

//
// We will check if this function call be called,
// once with "char*" and once with "int".
//
int f(int i) {
  std::cout << i;
  return i;
}

int main() {
  auto b1{has_f<char*>::value};
  std::cout << "test(char*) gives: " << b1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Just to make sure we can call f(int): ";
  f(777);
  std::cout << std::endl;
  auto b2{has_f<int>::value};
  std::cout << "test(int) gives: " << b2 << std::endl;
}
```

The output:

```
test(char*) gives: 0
Just to make sure we can call f(int): 777
test(int) gives: 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is that you're making an unqualified call to `f` here:

```
template<typename X>
static auto check(X const& x) -> decltype(f(x));
```

The `f`s that will be found will be those in scope at the point of definition of `check()` (none) and those that are found by argument-dependent lookup in the associated namespaces of `X`. Since `X` is `int`, it has no associated namespaces, and you find no `f`s there either. Since ADL will never work for `int`, your function has to be visible before `get_f_result` is defined. Just moving it up solves that problem.

---

Now, your `has_f` is overly complicated. There is no reason for the `substitution_succeeded` machinery. Just have the two `check()` overloads return the type you want:

```
template<typename T>
struct has_f {
private:
    template <typename X>
    static auto check(X const& x)
        -> decltype(f(x), std::true_type{});

    static std::false_type check(...);
public:
  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

And now `has_f<T>::type` is already either `true_type` or `false_type`.

---

Of course, even this is overly complicated. Checking if an expression is valid is a fairly common operation, so it'd be helpful to simplify it (borrowed from [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk), similar to [`std::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)):

```
namespace impl {
    template <template <class...> class, class, class... >
    struct can_apply : std::false_type { };

    template <template <class...> class Z, class... Ts>
    struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type { };
};

template <template <class... > class Z, class... Ts>
using can_apply = impl::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;
```

This let's you write:

```
template <class T>
using result_of_f = decltype(f(std::declval<T>()));

template <class T>
using has_f = can_apply<result_of_f, T>;
```

Comment: Bah, `is_detected` is in Library Fundamentals v2 and not all of Library Fundamentals **v1** got into C++17.  :(

Answer (score 2):

I can see 2 ways to fix the issue you are seeing:

1. Forward declare your function `f`. This is required because you are explicitly calling the function by name in the template `get_f_result`.

`int f(int);
template<typename T>
struct get_f_result {
private:
  template<typename X>
    static auto check(X const& x) -> decltype(f(x));
  static substitution_failure check(...);
public:
  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};`

2. The second solution is to make it more generic i.e not just for `f(c)` but for all function which takes an `int`:

```
//
// sfinae to derive the specialization
//
template <typename Func, Func f, typename T>
struct get_f_result {
private:
  template <typename X>
    static auto check(X const& x) -> decltype(f(x));
  static substitution_failure check(...);
public:
  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

And Call it like:

```
template <typename T>
struct has_f : substitution_succeeded <typename get_f_result::type> { };
```

Again here `f` needs to be known here..but, you can again make it more generic by shifting the responsibility of providing the function at the caller site.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on 1. ? I think the naive thinking is that declaration of `f` should not be needed before the instantation of the template which is done in `main` where `f(int)` is declared. It looks like the template "knows" it will fail.

Comment: @Arunmu `f` is a dependent name.

Comment: @Barry Ah..yes I always get confused. In that case it works as you explained with ADL and non-ADL lookup.